# Python - Choose random name from array without repetition until all have been chosen

Tags: python, arrays, random, repeat

I've just started learning Python so if this is something easy i apologise. I want to generate a random name from a set array of names, then not repeat that name again until all have been chosen and the cycle begins again. The code below is what i have already, this generates the random name, but repetition is happening.

```
import random

employee = ["adam", "Scott", "Michael", "Andrew", "Mark", "Fernando", "Faith", "Steve", "Lee", "Amani", "Liv", "Nick A", "James", "Jake", "Brett", "Graham", "Fraser", "Jacob", "Chelsea", "Phil", "George", "Charley", "Emma", "Steph"]
print(random.choice(employee))
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `random.shuffle(employee)` and then just iterate the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [**`random.shuffle()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) to shuffle the elements in your list:

```
import random

employee = ["adam", "Scott", "Michael", "Andrew", "Mark", "Fernando", "Faith", "Steve", "Lee", "Amani", "Liv", "Nick A", "James", "Jake", "Brett", "Graham", "Fraser", "Jacob", "Chelsea", "Phil", "George", "Charley", "Emma", "Steph"]
random.shuffle(employee)
for i in employee:
    print(i)
```

You can use `random.shuffle()` to randomize the order of your list and iterate over the list again as many times as you need.

Comment: Hi, this is shuffling the list and displaying the entire list, i would like to show one list item at a time.

Comment: @BrennanJenkins What do you mean? This prints each element one by one, not the entire list at once. The `for` loop iterates over each element of the list, stored in `i`.

Comment: Apologies, you're correct! This has done what i needed it too before my next steps. Thanks :)

Comment: @BrennanJenkins Great news! Good luck with your program :)

Answer (score 1):

One of two things should work, very similar:

(1) Make a copy of the list; choose items from the copy.  Every time you choose an item, remove it from the list.  When you empty the list, make a new copy and continue.

(2) Use the shuffling operations from itertools to give you a random permutation of the list.  Iterate through that.  When you get to the end, get a new random permutation.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `random.shuffle` as it does [in-place random shuffling of a list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

```py
import random

employee = ["adam", "Scott", "Michael", "Andrew", "Mark", "Fernando", "Faith", "Steve", "Lee", "Amani", "Liv", "Nick A", "James", "Jake", "Brett", "Graham", "Fraser", "Jacob", "Chelsea", "Phil", "George", "Charley", "Emma", "Steph"]

# Make 10 rounds of random selections
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    # Shuffle the list in new random order
    random.shuffle(employee)
    # Print a random employee without repetition in each round
    for random_employee in employee:
        print(random_employee)
```

Comment: Hi, this is shuffling the list and displaying the entire list, i would like to show one list item at a time then reshuffle when the end of that iteration is reached

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
import random

employee = ["adam", "Scott", "Michael", "Andrew", "Mark", "Fernando", "Faith", "Steve", "Lee", "Amani", "Liv", "Nick A", "James", "Jake", "Brett", "Graham", "Fraser", "Jacob", "Chelsea", "Phil", "George", "Charley", "Emma", "Steph"]

employeecopy = employee

while len(employeecopy) != 0:
  chosen = random.choice(employeecopy)
  employeecopy = list(set(employeecopy) - set([chosen]))
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/ConsiderableSurprisedShareware)